# Partial differentiation of $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$

Tags: partial-derivative

If $U=f(r)$ where $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$ , what is $U_{xx} + U_{yy} + U_{zz}=$ 

The result must be in terms of $r, f(r)$ and its derivatives only

---

I have obtained $f_x(r)=f^{'}(r)\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}= f^{'}(r) \frac{x}{r}$

I'm confused with $f_{xx}(r)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, as you write correctly, 
$$ \def\p#1#2#3{\frac{\partial^{#3} #2}{\partial #1^{#3}}}\p x{}{} f(r) = f'(r)\p x r{} $$
Taking another derivative, we have, using the product rule first
$$ \p x{}2 f(r) = \p x{}{}\left(f'(r) \p xr{}\right)
  = \p x{}{} f'(r) \p xr{} + f'(r) \p xr2$$
Using the chain rule in the first term as for the first derivative, gives 
$$ \p x{}2 f(r) = f''(r) \left(\p xr{}\right)^2 + f'(r)\p xr2 $$
Now, 
$$ \p xr{} = \frac xr, \quad \p xr2 = \frac{r - \frac{x^2}r}{r^2} = \frac{r^2 - x^2}{r^3}$$
Hence
$$ \p x{}2 f(r) = f''(r) \frac{x^2}{r^2} + f'(r) \frac{r^2 - x^2}{r^3} $$
Due to symmetry, the $y$- and $z$-derivatives are analogous.

Comment: the answer is $\frac{2}{r} f^{'}(r)+f^{''}(r)$

Comment: here $f(r)=r^2$ right?